# Prove that this space is not Banach

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded set with boundary $\partial\Omega$ of class $C^1$.
$$\mathcal{A}:=\{u\in C^2(\bar\Omega):u=0\text{ on }\partial\Omega \}$$
endowed with the scalar product
$$(u,v)_{\mathcal{A}}:=\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u,\nabla v)_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,dx.$$
I have to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ equipped with the induced norm is a normed space, but it is not a Banach space. I can't find a proper counterexample. Any help?

Comment: You know, I suppose, that the continuous functions are not complete in the $L^2$ norm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand you only need help in showing that $\mathcal A$ is not Banach. Таке а function $f\in C^1(\bar\Omega)$ such that $f=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $f$ is $C^2$ everywhere in $\bar\Omega$ except at a single point $x_0\in\Omega$, where the second derivatives do not exist. Then you can approximate $f$ in the norm defined by this inner product by functions $f_n\in\mathcal A$; thus, $\mathcal A$ is not complete in this norm and hence by definition not Banach.

Comment: I was thinking about whether or not this would be enough, or if one should prove that such a function exists for any $\Omega$ as described, do you think this is unnecessary?

Comment: Without loss of generality suppose that $0\in\Omega$ and take $x_0=0$. Let $r>0$ be small enough that the ball of radius $r$ lies in $\Omega$, let $\phi(x)$ be a smooth function supported in this ball such that $\phi(0)=1$. Set $f(x)=\phi(x)x_1|x|$.

Comment: Beautiful, I didn't realize we could take $0 \in \Omega$ and then work from there, was trying to do something far more complicated.

Comment: What do you mean for $x_1$ in the definition of $f$?

Comment: The first coordinate: $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$; just in case, $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$.

Comment: I missed the integral in the definition of the scalar product,  am sorry...!!!

Comment: Never mind, I even did not notice that, assumed automatically that it is there:) So my answer is just for this inner product (with the integral).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I'll try to use your hint!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: But how shall I reason to find a converging sequence in that norm?

Comment: set $f_j=f*\delta_j$, where $*$ stands for the convolution and $\delta_j=\psi(jx)j^n$, $\psi(x)$ being a smooth compactly supported function with $\int\psi(x)dx=1$. For sufficiently large $j$ the support of $f_j$ will lie inside $\Omega$ (so it will be zero on $\partial\Omega$); the convergence of $f_j$ to $f$ is ensured by the fact that $f$ has continuous first derivatives (which hence necessary lie in $L^2(\Omega)$).